# Making my node jump

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm moving my player with this code: Left and right along screen. In the center of the screen there is a "jumping artefact" which is supposed to make the player jump when the player touches it.

Problem is when my player is running and the jump starts. The player loses his (horizontal) `x.velocity`. Only jumps along vertical, and what I need is to preserve his `x.velocity`.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
    if(touchLocation.x >self.size.width / 2.0){

        player.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(100, player.physicsBody.velocity.dy);

    }else{

        player.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(-100, player.physicsBody.velocity.dy);

    }
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
    if(touchLocation.x >self.size.width / 2.0){

        player.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(5, player.physicsBody.velocity.dy);

    }else{

        player.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(-5, player.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
    }
}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }

    if((firstBody.categoryBitMask == playerCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == jumpingCategory) ||
       (firstBody.categoryBitMask == jumpingCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == playerCategory))
    {
       NSLog(@"player hits jumping");

       player.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(player.physicsBody.velocity.dx, 390.0f);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the velocity. **Apply an impulse instead**.

```
[player.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 1)];
```

This way it will preserve the current horizontal velocity value.

Comment: Good to hear it. Can you please accept my answer? :)

Comment: Do you mean "vote up"? "Vote up requires 15 reputation". I tried it. When I get this reputation points I'll be back to upvote ;)

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows).

As the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows.